# Creating Multiple Feature Classes as Views on Standalone Table in ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK

Tags: file-geodatabase, feature-class, sql-view, arcgis-pro-sdk

I'm developing an ArcGIS Pro 2.9 plugin using the .NET SDK. I have a set of data that contains fields describing points and ellipses to display on the map. I would like to create two FeatureClass layers to represent the points and ellipses defined by the data. From what I understand, each FeatureClass has its own backing Table that wants its own copy of the data.

Ideally, I would like to load the data into a standalone table in a FileGeodatabase and then create multiple FeatureClass layers as views into that 1 table. I know there is a way to create a TableView in ArcGIS Pro however I have not been able to find any way to create a "FeatureClass as a TableView".

My underlying goal here is to avoid having to duplicate data rows across all of my FeatureClass layers. This will also cause headaches as I will need to support fields being updated.

Comment: File  geodatabase doesn't have a backing RDBMS, so views aren't an option. You can use a Join to link each geometry table to the ancillary data table, but it'd probably more efficient to link the polygon to the attributes of the point feature class (joins are somewhat expensive, and points are "skinny", so don't have much overhead). You could also go the RDBMS route, but only if there's a good business case to justify the added cost (even a free RDBMS like PostgreSQL has a administrative and transaction overhead cost, and a full-blown enterprise geodatabase has a licensing cost, as well).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was actually able to programmatically create a TableView from a standalone Table on a FileGeodatabase and was able to see an edit on the standalone table cascade to the view table automatically. I don't need any associated query or filter  for the views, I just want it to use the same backing data so that edits will cascade. As for joining the the ellipse layer to the point layer: It looks like it will copy over the data from the point table but it doesn't seem to propagate updates if I edit the point layer values.

Comment: A TableView isn't a view, it's a temporary table: "The table view that is created by the tool is temporary and will not persist after the session ends unless the document is saved." A Join should honor updates; there should certainly be an index on the join column.